# Django Templates + jQuery + better way to do

Tags: jquery, django, templates

I wanna do something like a Pop Picture Game, when you have an album of pictures and have to answer the title of the picture, so I'm doing this using Django + Kickstrap + jQuery( for the logical code)

this is my template.

```
    <ul class="thumbnails" >
        <li class="span12" id="pops">
        {% for photo in pops.photos.all %}
            <div class="thumbnail span3" id="pop_picture">
              <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{photo.original_image}}"alt="{{photo.name}}">
              <br>
              <p id="answer">{{photo.name}}</p>
              <input id="txt_pop" type="text"  value=""/>
              <button id="pops_button" type="submit"  class="btn">confere</button>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}

        </li>
    </ul>
```

--myscript.js

```
function myCallback() {
    //do things!;
    if( $("#txt_pop").val() === $("#answer").text())
    {
        $("#pops_button").addClass("btn-success");
        $("#pops_button").text("CORRETO");  
    }else{
       $("#pops_button").text("ERRADO");
       $("#pops_button").addClass("btn-danger");
   }
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    //and then change this code so that your callback gets run
    //when the button gets clicked instead of mine.
    // **by the way, this is jQuery!
    $('#pops').find("#pops_button").click(myCallback); 
});
```

Two things are happen, first one:
How to pass {{photo.name}}, that's the answer, to use on my function on js.

The second, strange behavior is:
Just my first div class with id="pop_picture" works fine, any other pictures response well.

This question is a mix of: newbie on jQuery and templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use `id` for elements that occur more than once. That's probably why only your first one works and not the others. Same issue with `id="answer"` - use a class, and find it via jQuery.

```
{% for photo in pops.photos.all %}
        <div class="thumbnail span3" id="pop_picture">
          <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{photo.original_image}}"alt="{{photo.name}}">
          <br>
          <p class="answer">{{photo.name}}</p>
          <input class="txt_pop" type="text"  value=""/>
          <button class="btn pops_button" type="submit">confere</button>
        </div>
{% endfor %}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pops .pops_button').click(function() {
       alert($(this).parent().find('.answer').html());
    }); 


});
```